# Remove specific word from textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, text, textbox

Is it possible to remove a specific word from a textbox in vb.net 2010

example:
i have a textbox that says "Hello World"
and one that will copy it but only say "World"

my current code remove all letters.

```
textbox2.Text = New String(textbox2.Text.Except("Hello").ToArray())
```

thanks

Comment: yes, so textbox 2 is copying text from textbox1 but i want it to only copy World not the whole thing

Answer (score 3):

Use [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx).

```
textbox2.Text = textbox1.Text.Replace("Hello", "").Trim()
```

`Except("Hello")` will filter out each `H`, `e`, `l` and `o` and is not what you want.